# Python array to array conversion

Tags: python, arrays

**How to convert an array like:**

```
array([15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,  3,  8, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15,  6], dtype=int64)
```

**To:** and the reverse conversion ?

```
array([[15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [ 3],
       [ 8],
       [13],
       [13],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [ 6]])
```

".flatten(), .reval() are not solving this."

Comment: *How* did you try to use `flatten` or `reval`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reshape` for this.
Here's the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). Arguments in my code snippets below are `newshape` values:

> **newshape: int or tuple of ints** 
> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

```
a = np.array([15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,  3,  8, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15,  6], dtype=np.int64)
b = a.reshape(-1, 1)
b
```

Output:

```
array([[15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [ 3],
       [ 8],
       [13],
       [13],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [15],
       [ 6]])
```

For reverse transformation:

```
b.reshape(-1)
```

Output:

```
array([15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15,  3,  8, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15,  6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
a = np.array(
    [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 3, 8, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 6], dtype=np.int64
)

print(a[:, None])
```